# Plotting several lines with color depending on a row value

Tags: gnuplot

I have a matrix of m columns. I want to plot column n versus column 1 using the value of a selected row (in every column) to select the color.

Something like this:

```
plot  for [k=2:20] 'test.txt'  u 1:k notitle w lines linecolor "row 10 of column(k)"
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: with  ´stats "test.txt" index 0 every ::rowj::rowj  using columnk´ I can read value in (rowj,columnk), I understand that I can use something like ´plot for [k=2:200] "test.txt" i 0 u 1:k w l lc (stats 'test.txt' i 0 every ::10::10  using k)´  but I have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the color with the palette option:

```
# using column k+1 to select color
plot  for [k=2:20] 'test.txt' u 1:k:(column(k+1)) palette   

# using the value k+1 to select color
plot  for [k=2:20] 'test.txt' u 1:k:(k+1) palette
```

Since you want a color specified by row 10 of column k, I would try something like:

```
colors = system("sed -ne '10p' test.txt")
plot  for [k=2:20] 'test.txt' u 1:k:(word(colors,k)+0) palette
```

Comment: Thanks, with your first option I could select the color inside a line. But what I want is to select the colors of every line depending on the value of that line in a selected point. So, I can not use other column. At this moment I am preproccessing data to do this, but it is very time consuming.

Comment: (i.e. if the value of line 1 in row 20 is 20 then this line is green, if value of line 2 in row 20 is 25 this line is red,...)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You mean "if the value of line 1 in column 20 is 20 then..."? If so, have you tried the second option?

Comment: Sorry, I could not try your second option. I only have windows computers in my job and "sed" command is not working. I will try it in my house.

Comment: I found a work around using the following: `set multiplot

set palette defined (0 'green', 0.05 'yellow', 0.1 'orange', 1 'red')
set cbrange[0:1]

do for [k=2:76]{
    stats 'data.dat' i 0 every ::20::20 using k nooutput
    xs=STATS_mean
    xsw=2*STATS_mean+0.5
    plot[0:8000][0:1] 'data.dat' i 0 u 1:k:(xs) notitle w lines lw (xsw) lc palette
    }
unset multiplot`